# How to set the Z range in plot3d in Maxima/WxMaxima?

Tags: gnuplot, maxima

I want to plot a 3D function in Maxima/WxMaxima:

> u^2 - v^2

Using the manuals I put:

```
plot3d (u^2 - v^2, [u, -2, 2], [v, -3, 3], [grid, 100, 100],
    [mesh_lines_color,false])$
```

and this is what I get:

[image]

but I just want to get the positive values Z>0 . how can I set the range for Z?

This is strange that I can't find this anywhere in the documentation, because Maxima uses GnuPlot as a backend for plotting and there one can just easily set the zrange:

> set zrange [0.0:5.0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `gnuplot_preamble`:

```
plot3d (u^2 - v^2, [u, -2, 2], [v, -3, 3], [grid, 100, 100],
[mesh_lines_color,false], [gnuplot_preamble, "set zrange [0.0:5.0];"]);
```

Or you can just add z limits:

```
plot3d (u^2 - v^2, [u, -2, 2], [v, -3, 3], [z, 0, 5], [grid, 100, 100],
[mesh_lines_color,false]);
```

[image]